# How to $inc a field by another field in the same document?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

How do I use the value of another field in `$inc` to define how much to increase?

Example-

Some doc

`{_id: obi, length: 256, delta: 6}`

Here, I want to increase the length by delta increment.

Pseudocode would be

```
db.collection.update({}, $inc: {length: $delta});
```

Thanks for helping...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple update operation can't allow to use internal fields in another fields, either its any of the operators,

For the solution you can use [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) starting from MongoDB 4.2,

- use `$add`/`$sum` any operator from both to sum the both fields number

```
db.collection.update({},
  [{
    $set: {
      length: {
        $add: ["$length", "$delta"]
      }
    }
  }]
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3RTPbDa5w5C)